# Display incremented count from database table ID using Ajax

Tags: c#, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, controller

I want to get the last ID from a database table and increment by 1, to be displayed in an Input or Label parameter of HTML.

Most tutorials display it in tables. Here is my code:

index.cshtml

```
<td>Trans Id</td>
<td><input id="tbTransID" type="text" /></td>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/CashAdvance/GetTransID",
                data: "{}",
                success: function (data) {
                    var s = data.TransID;                     
                    }$("#tbTransId").html(s);
                }
            });
        });
</script>
```

CashAdvanceController

```
public ActionResult GetTransID()
{
     AcctgContext db = new AcctgContext();
     return Json(db.CATransactions.Select(x => new
     {
         TransID= x.TransID + 1
     }).ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your linq query in the controller as below:

```
public ActionResult GetTransID()
{
     AcctgContext db = new AcctgContext();
     return Json(db.CATransactions.OrderByDescending(i => i.TransID).Select(i=>new
     {
         TransID= x.TransID + 1
     }).FirstOrDefault(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

In your query, you are selecting list of values whereas you need only the max id to increment it.

Comment: Got it. Results from Network tab (inspect element) returned correct parameters. However, it didn't display on the Input parameter. Did I miss something on my script? Please tell me if this I need to create another Question.

Comment: Are you getting any error on the input parameter? I guess you just need to use **var s=data**

Comment: Done already. I just changed html(s) to val(s). It works now.